# ASP.NET MVC Routing - Keeping up with parameters through redirects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, coding-style, routes

I am working on my first real ASP.NET MVC project and I need a little advice.

So, let's say that my app has an admin section where you can create companies, departments, and users within each department.

Company -> Department -> User

Right now my urls are looking like this:

```
Companies/Index
Departments/Index?companyId=1
Users/Index?companyId=1&departmentId=2
```

It's getting complicated because if I have to redirect from the user list back to the department list, I have to do something like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Departments", new { companyId = model.CompanyId });
```

As things get more nested, I have to start passing more and more parameters so that the controller actions have the context that they need.

Is there a better way to structure the routes for controllers that have "nested" functionality like this?  Should they look more like:
Companies/{id}/Departments/{id}/Users  ?

Is there a good article that someone could link me to that can provide some advice for best practices when it comes to this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add more routes on your Global.aspx which maps Urls to actions
with more specific routes at the top.
You can have something like:

routes.MapRoute("user","Users/Index/{companyId}{departmentId}", new {controller="",action=""})
routes.MapRoute("department","Departments/Index/{companyId}",new { controller="",action=""})
routes.MapRoute("company","Companies/Index",new { controller="",action=""})

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I know that I can setup routes manually like that, but I still have to pass multiple route parameters to new controllers.  For instance, I've uploaded a photo for a user which was at 'companies/4/departments/16/users/26/photos/new' and in that action I need to redirect back to the photo list, which makes me pass companyId, departmentId, and userId manually to the new route.  This seems like a lot of manual coding that has a lot of room for error.  What I'm basically asking is, is that just the way it is, or is there some better pattern that I can follow?  Thanks!

Comment: @jdraper3 - Did you solve this elegantly? I'm currently facing the same situation and can't find much help on it out here on the internet. Any tips on your resolution would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I don't do a lot of straight MVC anymore, and mostly use angular these days, but there isn't really a magic solution like I was looking for at the time.  Storing the values in the model and passing them to the RedirectToAction method is just fine, and I was definitely overthinking it.